# How to properly limit the quantity of pieces for a singleton

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I've never been able to properly limit the quantity of pieces an editor can select when editing in context. This needs to be a singleton, as I understand, because an area offers many widgets.

In this case, there is only one type, and it can also be deleted, in case the editor does not want that placeholder filled.

However, when the editor wants to add a piece, what is the appropriate way to set that limit in code? All the options I pass are completely ignored, and [the documentation](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/reference/modules/apostrophe-pieces-widgets/#limitbyall) does not show a code example, only properties that can be used.

```
{{
  apos.singleton(
    container,
    'propName',
    'module-name',
    {
      limitByAll: 1,
      limitByTag: 1,
      limitById: 1,
      limit: 1
    }
  )
}}
```

None of the options limit anything for the editor:

[image]

So I wonder, what is the proper way to enforce a limit for a singleton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pieces widgets module does not include a maximum number of pieces allowed when individually selecting them.

This mode uses the [`joinByArray` field](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/reference/field-types/joinbyarray.html#settings). The `joinByArray` field *does* have an option, `limit` where you can specify the maximum number of joined pieces. But the pieces widget does not include that option.

If you know this will always be used to individually choose pieces (and not use the tag or "all" modes) then you might want to create a new widget for your needs. When using the "Individually" mode, the pieces widget isn't very fancy. It's simply a widget with a `joinByArray` field.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like a solution. It means completely redoing many of our components, so it's more likely that instead we will provide editors with the instructions to NOT select more than one, and simply pull the first one in the array of pieces in the templates. Thanks for the idea though, noted for next ones.

Answer (score 0):

I had often times problems to add options to singletons so I'm using singletons not often cause I found out that you can use an area for almost every case.

"This needs to be a singleton, as I understand, because an area offers many widgets."

You can use an area with only one type and limit the widget amount to one at least.

For example this is an area I create in gobal:

```js
// lib/modules/apostrophe-global/index.js

    {
      name: 'footerArea',
      label: 'Footer',
      help: 'Add a footer here which will be displayed on all pages'
      type: 'area',
      options: {
        limit: 1,
        widgets: {
          'footer': {
            controls: {
              movable: false,
              cloneable: false,
              removable: true,
              position: 'top-right'
            }
           }
         }
       }
    }
```

Unfortunately, the limit here only affects the amount of widgets that are in the area, not the pieces of the individual widgets.

I came up as well with `joinByArray` solution like [alexbea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/888550/alexbea) said:

```js
        {
            name: '_images',
            type: 'joinByArray',
            withType: 'apostrophe-image',
            label: 'Images',
            help: 'Add images to gallery',
            required: true,
            limit: 48,
            noHeight: true,
            filters: {
                projection: {
                    attachment: 1,
                    description: 1,
                    title: 1,
                    titleShow: 1,
                    titleColor: 1,
                    titleAlign: 1,
                    credit: 1,
                    creditUrl: 1,
                    clickAction: 1,
                    gradientColorTop: 1,
                    gradientColorBottom: 1,
                }
            }
    }
```

In my widget I can now easily show all the stuff of `_images` with an simple loop:

```js
{% for _image in piece._images %}

...

{% endfor %}
```

In a lot of cases this gave me more flexibillity cause I don't wanted to show a piece as it is. With this method I'm able to show one piece in many different widgets with different layouts. With the projection filters I can even decide which fields I pull for this specific widget. I can benefit more from apostrophes reusability and have a cleaner code like that.